# Windows 10 Ubuntu WSL freezes randomly when doing certain actions

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, freeze, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This has been happening quite a bit every time I do certain actions on a server such as listing all files `ls -la` and bash simply freezes and my only alternative is to start a new shell.

I looked at possible ways to resolve this such as enabling the following windows features which I do have them enabled;

- Windows Subsystem for Linux
- Virtual Machine Platform

I have also reinstalled WSL

I've also opened a new shell and ran the command `ps axo pid,wchan:32,cmd` to diagnose the freeze and the only info I get is;

```
sudo strace -p 14155
strace: Process 14155 attached
wait4(-1,
```

And just stays like that.

Any idea what I can do to resolve this issue please?

Comment: Have you tried to re-start wsl ?
In power shell type: wsl --shutdown
then start it again...
wsl

Comment: @Peter tried it but no luck :( tried also restarting LXSSMANAGER but no luck.